# Prove that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sin(\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\geq1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need to use the following inequality in a proof: $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sin(\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\geq1$. However, I don't know how I can justify or prove that this inequality holds. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you allowed to use as tools? What's your definition of $\sin x$?

Comment: Use Taylor series to show that $x>\sin(x)>x(1-\frac{x^2}{6})$ for $x<1$ and $x=\frac{1}{n}$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173299/does-the-maxima-of-sin-x-sin-sin-x-sin-sin-sin-x-sin-sin?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think could help,
$$\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}+1-1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

the series like for $|x|<1$ we have $$1-\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=1-(1+(-x)+(-x)^2+(-x)^3+\dots)=x-x^2+\frac{x^3}{1+x}$$

And here
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\dots$$

Comment: And because both series are alternating, we know that $$\frac{1}{n+1}\le\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\ge\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^3}.$$ This will suffice for $n\ge 2$, and for $n=1$, notice that $\frac{1}{2}=\sin\frac{\pi}{6}<\sin 1$ since $\frac{\pi}{6}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in (0.1]$ we only need to prove that $$\sin(x)\ge\frac{x}{x+1}$$
.
However,it is easy to prove that $$sin(x)\ge x(1-\frac{x^2}{6})$$

equivalent, we just need to prove that  $x(1-\frac{x^2}{6})\ge \frac{x}{x+1}( x\in (0.1])$this is trivial！